# iOS grouped buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I'd like to have a UINavigationBar at the top of my application, and below it I'd like to have something that looks like a navigation bar, but with buttons on it, like the bottom of the Maps application on the iPhone. How do you group buttons in this manner?

Comment: Reising1 - be sure to select the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a second UINavigationBar below the main UINavigationBar. Then just add a UISegmentedControl to the second UINavigation bar. I'm not sure if UINavigationBar is supposed to be used this way, but it looks and works fine. I've the technique in several apps.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Simple. Use a [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).